# vb6 how to know msflexgrid_scroll up down click

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

when clicking on the msflexgrid scroll bar on the down arrow, how can i know that i have clicked on the down arrow. give me sample code if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want it for (which defines how specific you need it to be).  You can tell when the grid has been scrolled successfully with the Scroll event:

```
Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Scroll()

    Debug.Print "Scrolled"

End Sub
```

If you need to distinguish down from up (and a single move from a larger bar-click move), you'll have to keep track of the top row:

```
Option Explicit
Public GridTop As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim lA As Long

    MSFlexGrid1.Cols = 4
    MSFlexGrid1.Clear
    For lA = 1 To 20
        MSFlexGrid1.AddItem lA & vbTab & "bob-" & lA & vbTab & lA & "-fred" & vbTab & lA & "-joe-" & lA
    Next lA
    MSFlexGrid1.RemoveItem 1
    GridTop = MSFlexGrid1.TopRow

End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_Scroll()

    Debug.Print "Scrolled"
    Debug.Print MSFlexGrid1.TopRow
    If MSFlexGrid1.TopRow = GridTop + 1 Then
        Debug.Print "Down arrow (effective)"
    End If
    GridTop = MSFlexGrid1.TopRow

End Sub
```

If you actually need to know when you've clicked the down-arrow specifically, whether or not it actually scrolls the grid, now you're into subclassing.  Try this:

http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=59656&lngWId=1

Just swap out a flexgrid for rtfExample in the sample project - I tried it, seems to work fine.